# Weird behavior with parameters on a ES6 Class

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, es6-class

I have a class, which contains a parameter called values. This is used to save values of points that represent specific shapes on a canvas.

I need to implement a functionality that lets me drag those shapes around, so I need to modify each specific point of the shape, removing from them the amount that was dragged.

So I decided that, as I trigger my mousedown event (which is the method StartMove), i would save the values of my points on a startValues variable, and as I move my mouse around (method move), I would then update the values, using startValues and the distance between the starting point and the current mouse position to determine my new point location.

The problem is, **this.startValues is actually getting changed to match this.values every time my cursor moves, and I have no idea why**. Is there anything simple I'm missing?

Since I store my values as values, and not coordinates (helps me with panning and zooming on the canvas), I first convert the values to position, then modify the position and then convert it back to a value. I've included the parent class, Grf, so you can see the methods which change values to position and position to values.

**Class with the problems**

```js
class Test {
    constructor(grf){
        this.grf = grf; // Another class, which contains important methods
        this.values = []; 
        this.startValues = []; 
    }

    startMove(p0){ // p0 = [x,y]
        const {grf} = this;

        this.startValues = [...this.values]; //I also tried this.startValues = this.values
        this.p0 = p0;

        grf.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',this.move);
        grf.canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', this.endMove);
    }

    move = (evt) => { // arrow function so 'this' is bound to Test class instead of grf.canvas
        
        const {grf, p0, values, startValues} = this;

        const coords = grf.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        const px = evt.clientX - coords.left;
        const py = evt.clientY - coords.top;

        for (let i = 0, iMax = this.values.length; i < iMax; i++){
            values[i][0] = grf.valX(grf.posX(startValues[0]) - (p0[0] - px));
            values[i][1] = grf.valY(grf.posY(startValues[1]) - (p0[1] - py));
        }

        console.log(this.startValues); // It changes to the same as this.values
    }

    endMove = (evt) => { // arrow function so 'this' is bound to Test class instead of grf.canvas
        const {grf} = this;
        grf.canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove',this.move);
        grf.canvas.removeEventListener('mouseup',this.endMove);
    }
}
```

**The other class**

```js
class Grf {
    constructor(canvas){ // Not the actual constructor, just an example of what the values could look like
        this.translateX = 1000;
        this.translateY = 1000;
        this.scaleY = 10.7;
        this.scaleX = 11.2;
        this.canvas = canvas;
    }

    posX (value){
        return (value-this.translateX)*this.scaleX;
    }

    posY (value){
        return (this.canvas.height-(100*(value))-this.translateY)*this.scaleY;
    };

    valX(pos){
        return (pos/this.scaleX) + this.translateX
    }

    valY(pos){
        return (-1)*((pos/this.scaleY) + this.translateY - this.canvas.height)/100
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How values are inserted into `startValues` and `values` in `Test` class? You probably insert exactly the same object in both without coping it so both arrays hold the same instances.

Take a look at the example:

```js
const obj = { a : 10 };
const a = [];
a.push(obj);
const b = [...a]; // creates new array, but with same objects
a[0].a = 20;
console.log(b[0]) // gives "{ a : 20 }"
```

To make it separate you need to make a copy of a object:

```js
a.push({...obj})
```

Comment: As you can see by this line in the code I posted, `this.startValues = [...this.values]`. So I'm destructuring it to make it different. I also tried doing something like `this.startValues = [...this.values, [0,0]]` just to make sure it wasn't the same value, and the result is still the same.

This is the only place in my entire code where this.startValues is assigned a new value

Comment: `[...this.values]` only makes sure that arrays are cloned, not object inside them. You have 2 different arrays but they hold exact same objects. You also need to clone objects inside these arrays, for example: `this.startValues = this.values.map(obj => ({...obj}));` - map also returns new array. That's why something like DeepClone exist in javascript and python. You may want to use library for this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-clone

Comment: Does this behaviour also apply to arrays within arrays?

Comment: The same behaviour applies to array within arrays

Comment: Yeah, and arrays inside arrays inside arrays. Generally arrays and objects are not copied by default, instead reference to an existing object/array is used. And [...array] and {...object} does not make deep copies